# Using java.nio.Paths raises weird exception in Clojure

Tags: java, clojure, interop

I'm trying to use static method from Paths class and I get this message:

```
user=> (java.nio.file.Paths/get "/tmp" "test.db")
ClassCastException java.lang.String cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;  hacking-capital.core/eval8240 (form-init317418023117164331.clj:1)
```

It should work according to [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html#get-java.lang.String-java.lang.String...-) but doesn't. Why?
I'm using 
Clojure 1.7.0 on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_66-b17, Linux

Comment: My guess is that the second argument needs to be an array. Maybe something like `(java.nio.file.Paths/get "/tmp" (into-array String ("test.db))`?

Comment: `String... more` is a `vargs` argument which is handled like an array. Which has been already mentioned by @assylias

Comment: You are both right:  `(java.nio.file.Paths/get "/tmp" (into-array String ["test.db"])) 
#object[sun.nio.fs.UnixPath 0x6099a03 "/tmp/test.db"]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The square brace character indicates an array, so the method is expecting an array of Strings

```
[Ljava.lang.String;
```

The Java API shows that Paths.get() takes a variable number of String arguments, but under the covers, this means that the method accepts an array.  I guess that Clojure does not do the necessary bundling of the String arguments into an array.

This [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html#varargs) shows that Java methods must be written to process an array of arguments.  In other words the javac compiler handles the variable number of arguments as a convenience.

Comment: What I found strange is that vargs in Java are understood as arg **and** array **not** just array in Clojure. So your answer seems to be incomplete without mentioning this quirk.

Comment: Neil, you meant "array of Strings" in the first line, right?